# How to insert huge data from PySpark dataframe to sql server table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse-analytics

I have nearly 38190123 rows of data to be pushed to SQL server table. I have tried the following:

```
 df.write.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbc_url).option("dbtable",target_table).option("user", username).option("password", password).option("batchsize", 100).mode("overwrite").save()
```

I have used reparation also, job is running forever in all the cases. Is there any way to push that dataframe at least slower if possible faster too.
Is there any parameter I need to look on/modify on SQL server database side ? I think here bulk insert is not required as 38190123 is smaller number for bulk insert. Can you suggest other than Bulk insert methods because I did not even know what's Bulk insert?

I am performing PySpark code in Azure Synapse.

Comment: if you can store/write your df somewhere like Azure blob storage and read it again, you can save on the time it takes to compute the df, which might help with the write operation to SQL server.

Comment: Yeah did it earlier ,like copied the dataframe to parquet to blob, and used copy activity to push that to sql . Its also taking time like now ,its running for an hour and throuhput is around 100 kb/s

Comment: Create an external table in Synapse that sits over the files in blob. You can then do insert a bit quicker and incrementally into an internal table in synapse dw.

Comment: is there any doc on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Increase batchsize from default 1000, also
Use SQL Spark connector [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/turbo-boost-data-loads-from-spark-using-sql-spark-connector)

Comment: Can you paste the exact pyspark code to be run using SQL Spark Connector? The Documentation has Scala code , need the pyspark equivalent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).